# Python: recursively import all files in a directory

Tags: python

I want to do something like this:

```
myprog --tests-dir /my/dir
```

which will recursively traverse `/my/dir`, find all Python files, and import them. An extra challenge is that there may be dependencies between them.

Example. If the files are like this:

```
/my/dir/a/__init__.py
/my/dir/a/x.py   (imports a.y)
/my/dir/a/y.py   (imports a)
/my/dir/a/b/__init__.py
/my/dir/a/b/z.py
```

this should result in:

```
import a
import a.y
import a.x
import a.b
import a.b.z
```

Maybe I could use [PathFinder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.PathFinder) somehow, but the details escape me.

Comment: Maybe build a list of files to import, then import them in a loop, ignoring errors, until the set of failing files goes to zero (you imported everything) or remains constant (you have actual dependency problems).

Comment: Fyi, Importing a.b.z automatically imports `a` `a.b` and `a.b.z` in order. I would recommend to have a module inside a and import that instead of complex / dynamic approach as it could be more error prone.

Comment: Use `os.walk()` to find each python file, and use `importlib` to import it.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Why would you want to import a lot of files automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following method with `importlib` and `os.walk` for one of my projects with a similar directory structure. This should recursively import all your `.py` files (excluding those starts with __)

```
import os
import sys
import importlib

def import_all_modules(root_dir, base_package=""):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.py') and not file.startswith('__'):
                module_name = os.path.join(root, file).replace('.py', '').replace('/', '.')
                if base_package:
                    module_name = base_package + '.' + module_name
                try:
                    importlib.import_module(module_name)
                    print(f"Imported {module_name}")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Failed to import {module_name}: {e}")

# Add the root directory to sys.path
root_dir = '/home/drown-filtering/src/'
sys.path.append(root_dir)

# Import everything from the root directory
import_all_modules(root_dir)
```

Modify the `root_dir` according to your own.

Comment: This works nicely. I moved the change of sys.path into the function, and undo the change before returning from the function, so the path won't get polluted.

Comment: This does not import `/my/dir/a/__init__.py` as `import a`, for example.

Comment: as I mentioned in my answer **this should recursively import all your .py files (excluding those starting with __)**